# How to use Stencil and Cover method to draw SVGs with metal ios?

Tags: ios, metal, metalkit

I did some research on how to render vector graphics with metal. But unfortunately i couldn't find any supporting resources. But there was an approach in OpenGL which is published by NVIDIA, to render SVGs using stencil and cover method. Read more here http://developer.download.nvidia.com/devzone/devcenter/gamegraphics/files/opengl/gpupathrender.pdf
. I am wondering if someone could help me out here to find out possibilities of rendering vector graphics using this approach with metal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no easy way implementing something this. Because Metal does not support vectors. You might have to calculate everything on CPU and rasterize.